# Home issue in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have uploade my code on test1.test.net server with my custom theme

all pages working fine excepting home page

test1.test.net- default luma theme home page

see
[image]

and on test1.test.net/index.php my custome theme home page coming

i have debug in pub/index.php and it's come in luma's home page not in my home page

i am using nginx server.

Comment: check web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url in core_config_data table

Comment: @RkRathod i have already checked and it's proper

Comment: check etc/sites-enable and hosts.php file

Comment: what is the identifier of your cms page used for homepage? if it is not home then you have to change default pages used for home page.

Comment: @SatishDubariya home

Comment: Check you have set the theme for both website and store

Comment: have you set your site's doc root `pub/index.php` instead of `index.php`?

Comment: Got the solution ..  it's related to varnish